# Inserting string from controller into `provide` tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to define a string called `index_title` and send it from a controller to a view and insert `index_title` into `<% provide(:title, index_title) %>` at the top of my view. Is this possible?

Edit: I have a few links in a dropdown tab in my _header file such as

```
<li><%= link_to "All Users", users_path, :tab => 1 %></li>
<li><%= link_to "DERs", users_path, :tab => 2 %></li>
...
```

and in my users_controller, I have the index action as

```
def index
  if params[:tab] == 1
    @index_title = 'All Users'
    @users = User.where(activated: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
  elsif params[:tab] == 2
    @index_title = 'DERs'
    @users = User.where(activated: true, der: true).paginate(page: params[:page])
  ...
  end
end
```

and my index view is

```
<% provide(:title, @index_title) %>
<h1><%= @index_title %></h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

but it won't change the @users list no matter the tab and it won't change the provided title or h1 title. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that `params[:tab] == 1` needed to be `params[:tab] == '1'`. The `@index_title` worked out fine as stated in the problem.